# Loop Mustache 10 times

Tags: mustache

I have JSON String like as follows

```
{
  Red:10,
  Green: 0
}
```

So I want to display the following line 10 times (as Red: 10 )

```
<img src="img/red.png">
```

How can I do that using Mustache ?

I tried

```
{{# Red}}
<img src="img/red.png">
{{/ Red}}
```

But it's not working

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do: You want to use the **Logic-less** Mustache like something like PHP.

But it's less than PHP. It does not offer the features of a whole hypertext-pre-processor language. It's just a template syntax and of course not turing complete.

So you can not write such a loop. Alternatively you iterate over an array for example:

This:

```
{
  "musketeers": ["Athos", "Aramis", "Porthos", "D'Artagnan"]
}
```

and this:

```
{{#musketeers}}
* {{.}}
{{/musketeers}}
```

gives you this:

```
* Athos
* Aramis
* Porthos
* D'Artagnan
```

---

But similar services offer this feature.
With [EJS](https://github.com/tj/ejs), this is possible:

```
<% for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++){ %>
    <img src="pic<%= j %>.png" />
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

From this page: http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

> If the **person** key exists and has a non-false value, the HTML between the pound and slash    will be rendered and displayed one or more times.
>
> When the value is a non-empty list, the text in the block will be displayed once for each item in the list. The context of the block will be set to the current item for each iteration. In this way we can loop over collections.

That means that you would need {# Red} to refer to a list of 10 items to do it this way. It doesn't seem that there is a concise way to represent a list of n items so you would be best off modifying your JSON to be something like

```
{
  Red: [
    { "value": "1" },
    { "value": "2" },
    ...
    { "value": "10" },
  ]
  Green: 0
}
```

I'm not sure, but you may need quotes around Red and Green as well. Depends how you're loading the JSON.

Mustache isn't really meant for doing stuff like this. It is, after all, logic-less templating. You should consider doing this with Javascript. You can look into using handlebars to use Mustache with Javascript.

Comment: Some Mustache implementations are versatile, and let you inject your own code, for instance for rendering `"{{# repeat(Red) }}<img src=\"img/red.png\">{{/ repeat(Red) }}}"` just fine. I don't know if Mustache isn't really meant for doing this stuff, but some library implementors don't like leaving their users helpless in the dust: https://gist.github.com/groue/5848907